# How to move a character rig file to another computer?

Tags: rigging, file-format

Every now and then I need to transfer files over from my work computer to my personal one when I'm working from home, but I've found that when I send over a file with a rigged character, it no longer works properly. For reference, this is what it looks like on the computer I made the rig on:[image: Correct rig]

And here's what it looks like when I send the file over to the other (in wireframe so you can see the lack of bones, there's no control rig in solid/material preview either):[image]

In pose mode, there's no control rig or bones, and if I select the rig from the outliner I can see the armature, but it's not correct, and doesn't function. Here's the outliner too: [image]
Which is how it looks on the original file too. I don't have any isuses like this sending over other blender files that don't contain a rig, so I'm not sure if there's a special procedure to sending rig files over. I'm not exporting anything out before sending, it's just the file itself.

Comment: I assume you have the same blender version on both machines?   Do you use the "File >> External Data >> Pack Resources" to have a self contained file to transfer?   Or at least certain that any external files are in the same relative positions?   Use the "File >> External Data >> Report Missing Files" to see if you have any external references that are not resolved, perhaps due to absolute paths that differ.   In your Outliner, upper left corner, change the *View Layer" drop-down to *Blender File* mode.  Do you

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's the same version, so I'll try doing that. Thank you!